# Insert additional row/item in Infopath

Tags: infopath2010

[image: snapshot of infopath]

[image: snapshot2]

I'm very new to Infopath.  I would like to know how to get the "Insert Item" to show up like the bottom image to add additional rows requiring the same info.  My design is the top image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to make sure your fields that you want to repeat are within a group:

[image: account grouping]

Then you need to make sure that the group is "Repeating" by right-clicking - Properties:

[image: repeating settings]

When you have done that, you drag'n'drop the group into your form as "repeating table". It should automatically displays the "insert item" link. You can customize this options by opening the properties of the repeating table though.

hope this helps